# Urlopen error when URL created by reading from file

Tags: python, python-2.7, urlopen

I had tried to find the solution in the Web, but didn't find quite full solution for me.

I'm trying to create an URL by concatinating variables from code and from file, but `urlopen()` return `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>`

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# _*_ coding: utf-8 _*_

from urllib2 import urlopen
from billmgrvars import * 
# These variables are from billmgrvars file
url = "https://" + dnsmgrIP + ":" + dnsmgrPort + "/dnsmgr?authinfo=" + resellerlogin + ":" + resellerpass + "&out=json&sform=ajax"

with open ("PTRlist.py") as PTRfile:
    for RRPTR in PTRfile.readlines():
        print (RRPTR)
        addPTRurl = url + "&clicked_button=ok&dtype=master&email=tech%40example.com&func=domain.edit&ip=&masterip=&name=" + str(RRPTR).replace("-", "%2D") + "&progressid=false&sok=ok&zoom-ip="
        print "URL: " + addPTRurl
        urlopen(addPTRurl)
PTRfile.close()
```

PTRlist.py file:

```
102.213.62.in-addr.arpa
43.24.212.in-addr.arpa
```

Running script:

```
102.213.62.in-addr.arpa

URL: https://1.2.3.4:1500/dnsmgr?authinfo=user:password&out=json&sform=ajax&clicked_button=ok&dtype=master&email=tech%40example.com&func=domain.edit&ip=&masterip=&name=102.213.62.in%2Daddr.arpa
&progressid=false&sok=ok&zoom-ip=
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./getPTRs.py", line 28, in <module>
    urlopen(addPTRurl)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 389, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1096, in do_request_
    raise URLError('no host given')
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>
```

Don't know why this error.

If I just run script like:

```
testVariable = "https://1.2.3.4:1500/dnsmgr?authinfo=user:password&out=json&sform=ajax&clicked_button=ok&dtype=master&email=tech%40example.com&func=domain.edit&ip=&masterip=&name=102.213.62.in%2Daddr.arpa
    &progressid=false&sok=ok&zoom-ip="
urlopen(testVariable)
```

It works correctly. Please, help and thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for that post. Changed console width and found that my strings are read from file with `\n` at the end, so URL is broken.

So the solution is:

`str(RRPTR).replace("-", "%2D").replace('\n', "")` as the part of my URL.